# Passing data using Accessor methods in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, accessor

I am pretty inexperienced with C++ however I need to use it for this project I am working on.  I am using and Arduino Mega to read and log an LED array.  I got the code working serially, but now I am trying to tidy it up a bit by defining my own library and classes. When I try and pass simple data like pin numbers and timeouts using accessors, They allways return 0. Or that seems to be the case when I try and print them on the serial port to test.  Here is my code

SedimentLogger.h

```
#ifndef SEDIMENTLOGGER_H
#define SEDIMENTLOGGER_H

#include "/home/marrabld/Programming/Arduino/arduino-1.0/libraries/QTRSensors/QTRSensors.h"
#include <Arduino.h>


#define NUM_SENSORS 8
//==================================================
// This header should hold 3 small classes used for :
//--------------------------------------------------
// 1. sedimentSensor
//     Dealing with sensorHardware
// 2. sedimentWriter
//     Reading and writing data
// 3. sedimentTimer
//     Reading and writing to the RTC
//--------------------------------------------------
// 
//==================================================

class sedimentSensor
{
 public:
  QTRSensorsRC sensor1;
  QTRSensorsRC sensor2;
  sedimentSensor(); //default constructor
  ~sedimentSensor();
  void  calibrateSensors();
  unsigned int *SensorValues1(){return sensorValues1;};
  unsigned int *SensorValues2(){return sensorValues2;};
  int SampleDelay(){return sampleDelay;};
  int EmitterPin1();


 private:
  // Map pins to LED numbers
  // first LED array
  int led1;
  int led2;
  int led3;
  int led4;
  int led5;
  int led6;
  int led7;
  int led8;
  int emitterPin1;
  //second Array
  int led9;
  int led10;
  int led11;
  int led12;
  int led13;
  int led14;
  int led15;
  int led16;
  int emitterPin2;

  int  timeout; // waits for 2.5 seconds for sensor outputs to go low
  long sampleDelay; // 1 second
  int numSensors;

  unsigned int sensorValues1[];
  unsigned int sensorValues2[];

};
```

sedimentLogger.cpp

```
#include "sedimentLogger.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <QTRSensors.h>
//#include "/home/marrabld/Programming/Arduino/arduino-1.0/libraries/QTRSensors/QTRSensors.h"
sedimentSensor::sedimentSensor()
{
  //Constructor
  int led1 = 24;
  int led2 = 26;
  int led3 = 28;
  int led4 = 30;
  int led5 = 32;
  int led6 = 34;
  int led7 = 36;
  int led8 = 38;
  int emitterPin1 = 22;
  //second Array
  int led9 = 25;
  int led10 = 27;
  int led11 = 29;
  int led12 = 31;
  int led13 = 33;
  int led14 = 35;
  int led15 = 37;
  int led16 = 39;
  int emitterPin2 = 23;

  int  timeout = 2500; // waits for 2.5 seconds for sensor outputs to go low
  int sampleDelay = 1000; // 1 second

  QTRSensorsRC sensor1 ((unsigned char[]) {led1,led2,led3,led4,led5,led6,led7,led8},numSensors, timeout,emitterPin1);
  QTRSensorsRC sensor2 ((unsigned char[]) {led9,led10,led11,led12,led13,led14,led15,led16},numSensors,timeout,emitterPin2);

  unsigned int sensorValues1[NUM_SENSORS];
  unsigned int sensorValues2[NUM_SENSORS];
};

sedimentSensor::~sedimentSensor()
{
};

int sedimentSensor::EmitterPin1()
{return emitterPin1;};

void sedimentSensor::calibrateSensors()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  unsigned int _delay = 500;
  delay(_delay);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  for(int i = 0; i<400; i++)
    {
      sensor1.calibrate();
      sensor2.calibrate();
    }
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  //TODO WRITE MAX AND MIN VALS TO FILE
  Serial.print("Array 1 Min :: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print (sensor1.calibratedMinimumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Array 2 Min :: ");
  for (int i = 0;i< NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print (sensor2.calibratedMinimumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("array 1 Max :: ");
  // print the calibration maximum values measured when emitters were on
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(sensor1.calibratedMaximumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("array 2 Max :: ");
  // print the calibration maximum values measured when emitters were on
  for (int 
  i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(sensor2.calibratedMaximumOn[i]);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  delay(_delay); 

};
```

Main.ino

```
#include <QTRSensors.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
//#include "/home/marrabld/Programming/Arduino/arduino-1.0/libraries/QTRSensors/QTRSensors.h"
#include "sedimentLogger.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "/home/marrabld/Programming/Arduino/arduino-1.0/libraries/RTClib/RTClib.h"

sedimentSensor sedLog;//= sedimentSensor();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sedLog.calibrateSensors(); 
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned int position1 = sedLog.sensor1.readLine(sedLog.SensorValues1()); // guessing its passing SensorValues as 0s
  unsigned int position2 = sedLog.sensor2.readLine(sedLog.SensorValues2());

  unsigned char i;
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(sedLog.SensorValues1()[i] * 10/10001);      
      Serial.print(' ');
    }
  Serial.println(position1);
  for (i=0;i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(sedLog.SensorValues2()[i]*10/1001);
      Serial.print(' ');
    }
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.println(position2);
  delay(sedLog.SampleDelay()); // No delay

  Serial.println(sedLog.SampleDelay()); // prints zero and shouldn't
  Serial.println(sedLog.EmitterPin1()); // prints zero and shouldn't
}
```

The calibrate sensors gets called as the LED turns on briefly as it should. But even the calibrated values that print out the serial port are junk.  If I write all of this code in the main loop it works as expected.

any help understanding what is going wrong would be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sedimentSensor` constructor, you are declaring new *local variables* with the same names as the member variables.
Remove the types from them to turn into assignments to the members.
Also put the `NUM_SENSORS` in the array declarations in the class definition.